# MiKteX not working when running from a compiled standalone(exe) app (INNOSETUP)

Tags: python, inno-setup, miktex

I am wondering If someone can help me or point me in the right direction. I created an app that creates a report. it does so by writting a latex file and then converted to a PDF. The app works fine. For the app to work i already have installed MiKteX

When I run the code from pycharm, it runs fine and makes the report. Then when I use pyinstaller and make it an executable, it also runs fine and makes the report. But when I make that executable with its respective folders into a compiled set-up file with INNOSETUP. The app runs well, but when it's time to make the report nothing happens.

I do not know if its a Miktex setting that I should change (i dont think so). Or most likely INNOSETUP setting maybe.